# Swift - Returning Value Assigned in Async Call (Firebase)

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, firebase, return

I am currently using Firebase and trying to get the count for number of children in a node to determine the rows for a section of a `UITableViewController`.  However due to the call being async it doesn't save properly outside.

Note: I assigned a value called "count" in the datatbase that is the number of children, but the actual function to count children is also async.

Here is my code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    var count = 0
    if section == 0 {
        ref.child("users").child("merchants").child(userID!).child("menu").child(spirits[section]).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let count = value?["count"] as? Int
            print("count in: ", count!)
        })
        print("count out: ", count)
    } else {
        count = 0
    }
    return count
}
```

Here is the output:

count out:  0 
count out:  0
count out:  0
count out:  0
count out:  0
count in:  1
count in:  1
count in:  1
count in:  1
count in:  1

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3UT8.png)

I have searched through multiple stack overflows questions that tried explaining dispatch or completion codes and I could not get anything to work.  How can I get my count to return properly?

Answer (score 0):

Never ever load data in one of the `numberOf...` table view data source methods. Get the data in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` and call `reloadData()` on the table view.

In `numberOfRowsInSection` just return the number of items in the model (the data source array).

There are countless examples how to use the table view data source and delegate methods properly.